# Deploy HTML file in java browser

Tags: java, html, css, swing, applet

I have a unique requirement i want my html files to be deployed on browser free platform. And when it comes to platform free and browser free only one word comes to my mind `applet` so i will like my HTML file(with css and js) to be rendered on an applet or swing window or some other stuff.

Any idea how to do it. Any new suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: I do not see how the applet helps in any way to achieve the stated goal.  Go with a free-floating desktop app.  I was about to suggest to use a `JEditorPane` for the HTML & styles, but note that it does not support JS.

Comment: Do you really mean an "applet"? Applets are Java programs that run inside a HTML document and thus in a browser, and if your system doesn't have a browser it can't run an applet. Do you mean a normal Java program maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you'd want a Swing applet to be rendered using HTML/CSS - that was exactly the point of creating Swing applets in the first place (so they don't relay on Web technologies).

If you really want a "browser free platform", I would suggest staying away from HTML/CSS/Javascript and writing a native app (Java / Windows / etc..)

Comment: my application produces HTML forms and need it to work without any browser

Comment: you'll need a BROWSER to parse and show your HTML forms - so I am not sure I follow your architecture logic... even if the browser is embedded in an app, it's still a browser ;-)

Comment: @Leon - can u please explain what u mean by "browser is embedded in app" Actually the thing is i have a tool that generates html js and css file which can be viewed on any browser, but i have some further requirement that this html file should work perfectly on all mobiles and tablets too.

Comment: by "browser embedded in app" I mean (like the others above) to package a browser within a stand-alone application (whether Java, .NET, whatever) so that your customers probably wont even be able to tell it's actually HTML. If you also have a requirement that this "should work perfectly on all mobiles and tablets too" then it's really browser based - on the mobiles the only way you'd be able to "embed a browser in an app" is by using something like PhoneGap (Mobiles Native wrapper or a browser window in which your app runs). Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Applets are running inside a browser, therefore it wont work, but you can create a standalone java GUI application that has an embedded browser in it. For example the [SWT browser](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-browser-widget/browser.html)

```
      import org.eclipse.swt.browser.*;
      ...
      Browser browser;
      try {
         browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.NONE);
         browser.setUrl("http://www.google.com");
      } catch (SWTError e) {
         MessageBox messageBox = new MessageBox(shell, SWT.ICON_ERROR | SWT.OK);
         messageBox.setMessage("Browser cannot be initialized.");
         messageBox.setText("Exit");
         messageBox.open();
         System.exit(-1);
      }
```

Or you can integrate the [lobobrowser](http://lobobrowser.org/java-browser.jsp)